# How can I have a composite key of a foreign key and other properties in EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, data-annotations, ef-fluent-api

I have the following classes:

```
    public class Apple
    {
        public int BoxID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("BoxID")]
        public Box Box{ get; set; }

        public int R { get => Color.R; set => Color = new Color (value, Color.G, Color.B); }

        public int G { get => Color.G set => Color = new Color (Color.R, value, Color.B); }

        public int B { get => Color.B set => Color = new Color (Color.R, Color.G, value); }

        [NotMapped]
        public Color Color { get; set; }    
    }

    public class Box
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<Apple> Apples { get; set; }
    }
```

What I would like is to get a schema such as:

Apple:
Primary (Composite) Key: BoxID (Foreign Key), R, G, B

Box:
Primary Key:  ID

What I've tried:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Apple>()
            .HasKey(a=> new { a.BoxID, a.R, a.G, a.B });
```

But it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Well just after posting this I solved it.
Basically, Fluent API allows us to make multiple calls to model builder:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Apple>()
            .HasOne(a=> a.Box)
            .WithMany(box => box.Apples)
            .HasForeignKey(a=> a.BoxID)
            .IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Apple>()
            .HasKey(a=> new { a.BoxID, a.R, a.G, a.B });
```